# How to get a list of available Mongoose Discriminators?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, discriminator

Given a situation where you have a User Scheme that you use to create a base model called User. And then for user roles, you use mongoose discriminators to create inherited models called Admin, Employee and Client. Is there a way to programmatically determine how many discriminations/inheritances/roles of the User model are available, as well as the available names?

My question in terms of code:

**File**: models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var options = {discriminatorKey: 'role'};

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
},options);

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

var Client = User.discriminator("Client", mongoose.Schema({
  Address : String,
  Tax_identification : String,
  Phone_number : String,
  Internal_Remarks : String,
  CRM_status : String,
  Recent_contact : String,
}));
var Employee = User.discriminator("Employee",mongoose.Schema({
  Staff_Id: String,
}));

module.exports = {User: User, Client: Client, Employee: Employee };
```

**File**: controllers/usersController.js

```
var User = require('../models/user.js').User;


module.exports = {
  registerRoutes: function(app){
     app.get('user/create',this.userCreateCallback)
  },

  userCreateCallback: function(req,res){

    //Get Available User Roles - The function below doesn't exist, 
    //Just what I hypothetically want to achieve:

    User.geAvailableDiscriminators(function(err,roles){

      res.render('user/create',{roles:roles})      

    });

  }
};
```

I hope I managed to express what I want to do. Alternative approaches are also welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [v4.11.13](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/commit/5d5be8ff63509267cc5f82c4efa08bab4ed74a52), mongoose model has `model.discriminators` which is an array of models, keyed on the name of the discriminator model.

In your case if you do `console.log(User.discriminators)` you will get:

```
{
  Client: {
    ....
  },
  Employee: {
  }
}
```

As far as I can see, this is [not documented anywhere](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html).

Line 158 in [`lib.helpers.model.discriminators.js`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/5d730d4fc2419d245495d166d553143290c4930e/lib/helpers/model/discriminator.js) is where this is created.

Comment: i think it is mentioned in the mongoose API docs, but not at a usual place :).


http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-discriminators

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to fetch the names and values of all the discriminators as for the names you can simply use

```
User.discriminators
```

but for finding values you can use this

```
return Promise.all(Object.keys(discriminators).map(i => 
    discriminators[i].find({ userId: this._id }))
).then(promiseResults =>
    promiseResults.reduce((arr, el) => arr.concat(el), [])
);
```

you need to put userId under each discriminators for that.