# Correct way to determine discriminator type after find

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'd like to use the correct mongoose model to represent a document which has several discriminators.

Say I have the following model:

```
const membershipSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  course: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Course' },
  price: { type: Number, required: true, get: p => `£${p}.00` }
}, { discriminatorKey: 'type' });

const subscriptionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  frequency: {
    type: String, enum: [ 'week' , 'month' ],
    required: true, get: val => `${val}ly subscription` }
})

const ticketSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  frequency: { type: String, default: 'one-off' }
});

const Membership = mongoose.model('Membership', membershipSchema);
const Subscription = Membership.discriminator('Subscription', subscriptionSchema);
const Ticket = Membership.discriminator('Ticket', ticketSchema);

module.exports = { Membership, Ticket, Subscription };
```

When I `.find` a set of `memberships`, I don't know in advance whether they are `ticket`s or `subscription`s.

I am currently doing something like this to find the subscriptions a particular user has:

```
  const { Membership, Subscription, Ticket } = require('./membership');      
  return Membership.find({ user: this._id });
```

But the `Membership` model doesn't have the correct getters, which are specified on the discriminators, `Subscription` and `Ticket`.

I know I have the `type` key to tell me whether a particular document is a Subscription or a Ticket.

But what is the *correct* way of getting each document to be represented with the correct model?

Comment: All the resources I can find, such as [this](https://anthonychu.ca/post/cosmos-db-mongoose-discriminators/) or even [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) give no advice on this issue.

Comment: I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51245618/2071807) which demonstrates how to find the discriminator models of a parent model. I'll use this to update my answer.

Answer (score 7):

I've solved this the hard way, but this *cannot* be the right way to do it. In the absence of any documentation to help though, this way will have to do:

```
  const { Subscription, Ticket } = require('./membership');
  return Promise.all([
    // Find each type of discriminator in turn
    Subscription.find({ course: this._id }),
    Ticket.find({ course: this._id }),
  ]).then(membershipArray =>
    // Combine the resulting arrays into a single result array
    membershipArray.reduce((combined, array) => combined.concat(array), [])
  );
```

Improvements/suggestions welcome.

---

### Update

The mongoose API make `model.discriminators` available, although this appears to be completely undocumented.

We can use this to call `find()` for every discriminator using `map`:

```
const discriminators = Membership.discriminators;

return Promise.all(Object.keys(discriminators).map(i => discriminators[i].find({ course: this._id }))
).then(promiseResults =>
  promiseResults.reduce((arr, el) => arr.concat(el), [])
);
```

This is a fairly straightforward way to get the correct discriminator every time, assuming that none of your documents are stored against the parent model.

If they are, it is fairly straightforward to append the parent model to the `discriminators` object before running the `Promise.all` line.